# Embed wmv hides dropdown/floating objects in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, embed, wmv

I've tried many tricks found on the web including:

- wmode transparent
- z-index
- WindowlessVideo

But none of them seem to work on Chrome. Works fine on IE and FF.

This version of code is XHTML compliant:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>wmv embed test</title>
<style type="text/css">
#floatingbar { background: thistle; z-index: 9999; position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 60px; border: 1px solid blue; }
#floatingbar2 { background: white; z-index: 9999; position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 60px; border: 1px solid orange; top: 140px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="floatingbar"></div>

<object type="application/x-mplayer2" style="width:260px; height:200px;" data="http://nov-exl.com/test/FactFinders.wmv">
<param name="movie" value="http://nov-exl.com/test/FactFinders.wmv" />
</object>

<div id="floatingbar2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to crop the video, you could put it in a div tag with overflow set to hidden.  Something like this:

```
<style> 
div#crop {position:absolute;height:100px;top:60px;overflow:hidden}
object, param {position:absolute;top:-60px}
</style>

<div id=crop><object><param /> </object></div>
```

If you wanted a more custom border or something for your videos, you might be out of luck when it comes to Chrome.

Comment: Not trying to crop the video, just demonstrating that any floating objects are hidden behind the video. So any popup/dropdown css menu won't work.